# Stuck on SEDSED

Tags: sed

I am trying to use [SEDSED](http://aurelio.net/projects/sedsed) by Aurelio Jargas.  I am running Cygwin.  I have installed the latest version of Python and modified the path.  I downloaded the SEDSED source code and it has a PY extension.  Afterwards, I am a bit lost as to what needs to be done.  I have checked around without much luck.  Hence, I thought I would post my question online.  Any guidance / help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`cd` to the same directory as `sedsed.py` then run:

```
chmod +x ./sedsed.py
mv ./sedsed.py /usr/local/bin/sedsed
```

Then you can run it from the command line with just:

```
prompt$ sedsed
```

also you say you have the latest version of Python. You'll need Python 2.x **not** Python 3.x the latest compatible version is Python 2.7.3 which can be installed through the Cygwin setup